# connecting elements

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("student")[0].onclick = addStudent("new element",text here ",document.getElementsByClassName("Class")[0]);
function addStudent(name,text,hendle)
{
var div=document.createElement("div");
var dt=document.createElement("dt");
var strong=document.createElement("strong").innerHTML = name;
var dd=document.createElement("dd").innerHTML = text;
dt.appendChild(strong);
div.appendChild(dt);
div.appendChild(dd);

div.setAttribute("class","student");
hendle.appendChild(div);
}
</script>`
```

---> when i run the script i get an error on firebug :

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0         [nsIDOMHTMLElement.appendChild]
[Break On This Error]
```

dt.appendChild(strong);

---> and also the this script don't work..the script position is in the end of the page.
how to fix it? (i'm only starting to learn javascript)

Comment: Please consider choosing a best answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

This statement doesn't do what your code assumes it does:

```
var strong=document.createElement("strong").innerHTML = name;
```

That sets the variable "strong" and the "innerHTML" property of the DOM element to the value of "name".  I think you want this instead:

```
var strong = document.createElement("strong");
strong.innerHTML = name;
```

Same for the `<dd>` you create.

Answer (score 0):

With these, you're assigning the value assigned to `innerHTML`  to the variable.

```
var strong=document.createElement("strong").innerHTML = name;
var dd=document.createElement("dd").innerHTML = text;
```

You need to store the element in the variable, then apply the `.innerHTML`

```
var strong=document.createElement("strong");
strong.innerHTML = name;
var dd=document.createElement("dd");
dd.innerHTML = text;
```

---

FWIW, I'd rewrite this code like this:

```
function addStudent(name, text, hendle) {
    var div = hendle.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

    div.classname = "student";

    div.appendChild(document.createElement("dt"))
       .appendChild(document.createElement("strong")).innerHTML = name;

    div.appendChild(document.createElement("dd")).innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strong` is `string` not a element

and if you want call a method on click you should provide function reference.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("student")[0].onclick = function(){

      addStudent("new element",text here ",document.getElementsByClassName("Class")[0]);
     }
```